# postfix/proxymap: request for unapproved table

Tags: postfix

I get this in my maillog

```
Jan 14 13:48:58 ovz postfix/proxymap[25328]: warning: request for unapproved
 table: "btree:/var/lib/postfix/postscreen_cache
 btree:/var/lib/postfix/postscreen_cache
 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.1.2*1
 wl.mailspike.net=127.0.0.[18;19;20]*-2
 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.1*-2"
Jan 14 13:48:58 ovz postfix/proxymap[25328]: warning: to approve this table for read-write 
 access, list proxy:btree:/var/lib/postfix/postscreen_cache
 btree:/var/lib/postfix/postscreen_cache   
 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.1.2*1
 wl.mailspike.net=127.0.0.[18;19;20]*-2
 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.1*-2 in main.cf:proxy_write_maps

Jan 14 13:48:58 ovz postfix/postscreen[25394]: fatal: 
 proxywrite service is not configured for table
 "btree:/var/lib/postfix/postscreen_cache     
 btree:/var/lib/postfix/postscreen_cache  
 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.1.2*1
 wl.mailspike.net=127.0.0.[18;19;20]*-2      
 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.1*-2"
```

But I have already done that, I believe:

```
proxy_write_maps = proxy:btree:/var/lib/postfix/postscreen_cache
  btree:/var/lib/postfix/postscreen_cache
  hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.1.2*1
  wl.mailspike.net=127.0.0.[18;19;20]*-2
  hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.1*-2
```

Postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mydestination = $myhostname, ovz.neland.dk, localhost.neland.dk, neland.dk, localhost
myhostname = ovz.neland.dk
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = local:/opendkim/opendkim.sock local:/opendmarc/opendmarc.sock
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
postscreen_access_list = permit_mynetworks, cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access.cidr
postscreen_bare_newline_enable = no
postscreen_blacklist_action = drop
postscreen_cache_cleanup_interval = 24h
postscreen_cache_map = proxy:btree:$data_directory/postscreen_cache btree:/var/lib/postfix/postscreen_cache hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.1.2*1 wl.mailspike.net=127.0.0.[18;19;20]*-2 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.1*-2
postscreen_dnsbl_action = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_sites = b.barracudacentral.org=127.0.0.2*7 dnsbl.inps.de=127.0.0.2*7 bl.mailspike.net=127.0.0.2*5 bl.mailspike.net=127.0.0.[10;11;12]*4 dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.10*8 dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.5*6 dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.7*3 dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.8*2 dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.6*2 dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.9*2 zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.[10;11]*8 zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.[4..7]*6 zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.3*4 zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.2*3 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.2*3 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.4*1 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.1.2*1 wl.mailspike.net=127.0.0.[18;19;20]*-2 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.1*-2
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 8
postscreen_dnsbl_ttl = 5m
postscreen_greet_action = enforce
postscreen_greet_banner = $smtpd_banner
postscreen_greet_ttl = 2d
postscreen_greet_wait = 3s
postscreen_non_smtp_command_enable = no
postscreen_pipelining_enable = no
proxy_read_maps = proxy:btree:/var/lib/postfix/postscreen_cache btree:/var/lib/postfix/postscreen_cache hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.1.2*1 wl.mailspike.net=127.0.0.[18;19;20]*-2 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.1*-2
proxy_write_maps = proxy:btree:/var/lib/postfix/postscreen_cache btree:/var/lib/postfix/postscreen_cache hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.1.2*1 wl.mailspike.net=127.0.0.[18;19;20]*-2 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.1*-2
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 10s
smtpd_hard_error_limit = ${stress?1}${stress:5}
smtpd_milters = local:/opendkim/opendkim.sock local:/opendmarc/opendmarc.sock
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/.../fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/.../privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```